# Assign user values for whole controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm developing my first laravel app, and I want to manage different actions on my controllers depending on user role and id.

So I'm wondering if I can add two private variables `$userRole` and `$userId` to my controller so I don't need to call `auth()->user()->role` and `auth()->user()->id` in each single action method.

I've tried to initiate the variables on __construct method, but the middleware seems not to be active at this point, and cannot access user() parameters.

I've tried also to just assign my variables with the `auth()->user()->whatever`, but seems that php load these values on compile time, so methods cannot be used for the initialization.

Now I'm wondering if I should create my own middleware for this (I will use it on several different Controller classes) or if I should use sessions.

Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session middleware has not ran by the time your controller is created.

You can add a controller middleware that can assign these values for you, as the middleware will run in the stack:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->userId = $request->user()->id;
        $this->roleId = $request->user()->role;

        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Another similar question and answer:
[Auth::user() is null in new route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660711/authuser-is-null-in-new-route/58663688#58663688)

Comment: I've tried this yesterday, following the answer you linked. Although then it failed, today I've managed to make it work.

Comment: do you think this can be done inside a proper middleware?

Comment: yes, you can access the controller the route is pointing to and add these values in a middleware class `if ($controller = $request->route()->controller) { $controller->userId = $request->user()->id; ... }`

Comment: Thank you very much! I was quite sure it should be possible, but was crazy trying to figure how to reach the controller object