# How to set the global variable on Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, controller

Everyone.

Every function on a controller, I am using the same variables.

```
public function store(Request $request) 
{
   $user = auth()->user();
   $user_name = $user->name;
   $user_id = $user->id;
   $init_pdf = url('/') . '/images/' . 'upload/' . $user_name . '/' . $name;
   ...
}

public function signedPdf(request $request) 
{
   $user = auth()->user();
   $user_name = $user->name;
   $user_id = $user->id;
   $name = $user_name . $user_id . '.' . $file->extension();
   ...
}
```

I want to set the global variable for the common variables.

How can I set it?

thanks

Comment: why are you storing the name and id of the user in different variables ? why not directly use `$user->name` & `$user->id` where you need them ?

Comment: I am not storing these variables, I am going to use it on another role.

Comment: still doesnt explain why you're setting other variables for them ? are you assigning `$user` variable again ? even so, it doesnt explain anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can directly set things in the constructor but there is an issue with Controllers in regards to middleware. The Controller is resolved before the request has passed through the middleware stack. Which means you usually won't have things like sessions or auth available yet. You would want to use a closure based middleware in the constructor of the Controller to be able to set this value:

```
protected $user;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        $this->user = $request->user();

        // also can set other variables here as well

        // let the request continue through the stack
        return $next($request);
    });
}
```

Then you should have access to `$this->user` in your methods.

Another answer: [Assign user values for whole controller in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58808551/2109233)

Duplicate of that basically.

Comment: how is this different from using `request()` helper and getting user?

Comment: how is it different in what way? ... `request()` `Request::` `$request` etc are all going to be the same instance ... doesn't matter how you get the user at all (could use `Auth::user()`, `auth()->user()`), the point is that you don't have access to the session until after the middleware stack has ran

Comment: and its not the entire stack, its just `StartSession` that needs to be ran before Auth could use the session to resolve the user; but that middleware is part of the `web` group of middleware

Comment: why would you not use `Request` instance in your method rather than adding `$this->middleware(...` in the constructor? You can already reach to you request regardless where you are.

Comment: its not "my method" its the OP's ... they want the user and other variables as properties of the controller class (my interpretation of what they mean by "global variables" in regards to the controller) ... ask the OP why they don't want to use that, not me

Comment: dude don't be hating your suggested answer is what I don't agree with. I am just asking the question as to what benefits you/OP is getting with implementation. if OP needs to access user details then this implementation doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @usrNotFound I am not the OP, I can not tell you why they are asking for what they are asking for; you have the ability to ask them to clarify what they want and why ... i am not "hating" bro, I am just not going to speak for the OP, I am not them, we are different people ... i am just providing the answer to what I think they ASKED for ... ask them if you want the answer to why THEY want something or why THEY think they want it

Answer (score 0):

**This solution is worked for me**

In

> app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php

Import **Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth; <--- like this

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $userId;
    protected $userName;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->userId = Auth::user()->id;
        $this->userName = Auth::user()->name; <--- "Admin"

    }
}
```

> Now **$this->userId** and **$this->userName** is available wherever extends Controller

**For example:**

> app/Http/Controllers/API/v1/ConfigController.php

```
 class ConfigController extends Controller
 {

   public function index() {
       return $this->userName; <--- "Admin"
   }
```